# What is the purpose of -e in sed command?

Tags: linux, shell, text, sed, command

I can't find any documentation about the `sed` `-e` switch, for simple replace, do I need it?

e.g.

```
sed 's/foo/bar/'
```

VS

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/'
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't find this in `man sed`?

Comment: You don't find potongs explanation, why not to use "cmd1;cmd2"

Comment: @BoltClock, I think they should check the texinfo instead, to know what are "sed scripts" since the the use of word "script" in the manual page is confusing with its usual use.

Answer (score 62):

From the man page:

```
-e script, --expression=script

    add the script to the commands to be executed
```

So you can use multiple `-e` options to build up a script out of many parts.

```
$ sed -e "s/foo/bar/" -e "/FOO/d"
```

Would first replace `foo` with `bar` and then delete every line containing `FOO`.

Comment: So, you don't need '-e' if you only have one script, right?

Answer (score 27):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '/foo/i\' -e 'bar' -e '/fred/a\' -e 'barny' -e '/harry/c\' -e 'potter' file
```

In each case the `i`(insert),`a`(append) and `c`(change) commands need to be terminated by a newline.

Normally commands can be separated by a `;` e.g. `/foo/d;/bar/d` and grouped by `{...`} e.g. `/foo/{h;d}` but for the `i,a,c` commands the `-e` provides a way of separating the commands.

The alternative is to use the shell(bash) to insert a newline:

```
sed '/foo/i\bar'$'\n''/fred/a\barney'$'\n''/harry/c\potter' file
```

Comment: On at least some sed implementations (for instance, on FreeBSD), you also need to end labels and branch commands using newlines/`-e`, rather than with semicolons. This won't work: `sed ':a; /x/ { s/x/y/g; ba }; q' <<< "jxm"`. But this will: `sed -e ':a' -e '/x/ { s/x/y/g; ba' -e '}; q' <<< "jxm"`

Comment: I'm not sure how necessary is the `must be terminated with a newline` phrase means here. When I tested here in my `cygwin`, this works: `sed '/foo/i\bar' file`. So now that we can fuse together the separate expressions into one, this raises again to the original question: What is the true purpose of the `-e` ?

Answer (score 12):

In the help for `sed` you will find that `-e` flag stands for:

```
 -e script, --expression=script
              add the script to the commands to be executed
```

You are not the first to be confused after encountering `-e`. In your example `sed 's/foo/bar/'` and `sed -e 's/foo/bar/'` are equivalent. In both cases `s/foo/bar/` is the *script* that is executed by sed. The second option is more explicit, but that is probably not the reason that you often see `-e` used. The reason for that is that `-e` makes it possible to use more than one script with the same invocation of `sed`. That still leaves the question why use it if you are using only one script? The following example might explain that:

`echo "foo" | sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/bar/foo/'`

Will output "foo".

However,

`echo "foo" | sed 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/bar/foo/'`

will fail because now `sed` interprets the first `s/foo/bar/` as a filename. Hence, to make life easier for future you, you can already start using the `-e` flag today. That way future you can just append the command with an extra script by using `-e <script>`.

N.B. In other answers using `;` as an alternative to use multiple scripts has been suggested. While that is technically possible in some cases, it is not encouraged, because it quickly leads to very hard to read code. See an example here: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-61

Answer (score 5):

`-e`, equivalent to `--expression`, is optional, unless you are stringing several expressions together (not common) as shown in another [Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33159/227169).

Aside: `;` can be used instead in the same expression to execute several expressions one after the other.