# sed insert in the beginning of multiple files is not working

Tags: shell-script, sed

I came across **a lot** of answers, including theses:

- [sed on OSX insert at a certain line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52131/sed-on-osx-insert-at-a-certain-line)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846304/sed-command-error-on-macos-x
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266281/how-to-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-all-files-in-a-folder

And I can't find a way to do what I want to do. I need to insert `#encoding:utf-8` at the beginning of every `.html.erb` file of my directory (recursively). I tried using this command

```
find . -iname "*.erb" -type f -exec sed -ie "1i \#encoding:utf-8" {} \;
```

But it throws this error:

> sed: 1: "1i #encoding:utf-8": extra characters after \ at the end of i command

Comment: You should process step by step. First make sure your *sed* command is ok, then combine it with the *find* command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To edit file in-place with [OSX sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html), you need to set empty extension:

```
$ sed -i '' '1i\
#encoding:utf-8' filename
```

And you need a literal newline after `i\`. This is specified by [POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Only [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) allows text to be inserted on the same line with command.

`sed` can also works with multiple files at once, so you can use `-exec command {} +` form:

```
$ find . -iname "*.erb" -type f -exec sed -i '' '1i\
#encoding:utf-8' {} +
```

Comment: @Thomas: yes, it's specified by POSIX. You can read the link I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '1i|#encoding:utf-8' -cx file
```

1. `1` select line 1
2. `i` insert text and newline
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways of doing what you want:

1. `sed`

   ```
   find . -iname "*.erb" -type f -exec \
    sed -i '' '1s/^/#encoding:utf-8\n/' {} \;
   ```

   I don't have access to a BSD `sed` to check, so I can't guarantee that the `\n` will be read correctly. Try the command on a single file and without the `-i` first to make sure.
2. Perl

   ```
   find . -iname "*.erb" -type f -exec \
       perl -i -pe 'print "#encoding:utf-8\n" if $.==1;' {} \;
   ```
3. shell

   ```
   find . -iname "*.erb" -type f -exec \
       sh -c 'echo "#encoding:utf-8" >tmp && cat "$1" >> tmp && mv tmp "$1"' sh {} \;
   ```