# adding strings in the beginning of the file

Tags: sed

```
$ ls *
2000-01-01-abcd.md
2000-01-01-cdef.md
```

I can extract abcd and cdef from the following command

```
 find *.md -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed 's/.md//' | sed 's/2000-01-01-//'" \;
```

I know how to add a string in the beginning of the file via `sed '1s/^/string/'` , but how do I pass the exact string?

How do I pass this string "abcd" and "cdef" in the corresponding files, because I want to add the corresponding strings in each and every file in the beginning of the file.

Comment: What do you want the filenames to be in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is the closest to what I was looking for. The idea of a tmp buffer solves the purpose. Other solutions hint towards for loops which in my opinion is already taken care by find -exec combination.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197400/119007

```
find ./ -name '*.md' -exec sh -c "echo '{}' | sed 's/.md//' | sed 's/2000-01-01-//' > tmp && cat {} >> tmp && mv tmp {}" \;
```

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely

Comment: That seems quite convoluted. [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391452/203203) below seems to do the same and is much simpler.

Comment: @xhienne : it might be simpler, but the simplicity was not important, instead, how to do with find -exec as asked in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

> to add the corresponding strings in each and every file in the
>   beginning of the file

***bash*** + ***sed*** approach:

```
for f in *.md; do fn=${f##*-}; sed -i "1 s/^/${fn%.*} /" "$f"; done
```

---

- `fn=${f##*-}` - truncating the longest matched sequence from the left till the last occurrence of `-` (for ex. `abcd.md`)
- `${fn%.*}` - truncating the rightmost sequence (from the end) till the 1st occurrence of `.`(dot) from the previous substring `fn` (i.e. `abcd`)
- `sed -i "1 s/^/${fn%.*} /" "$f"` - add the needed string to the beginning of the file

Comment: As an alternative, if the filenames are all the same size, you can also use: `for f in *.md; do sed -i "1 s/^/${fn:11:4} /" "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the `*.md` in your `find` command, or it will be expanded to matching names when you run it. You should also never use `{}` in a quoted context (see e.g. [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely)).

Here's a shell loop solution:

```
for name in ./*.md; do
    prefix="${name%.md}"             # "./2000-01-01-abcd.md" --> "./2000-01-01-abcd"
    prefix="${prefix##*-}"           # "./2000-01-01-abcd"    --> "abcd"

    { echo "$prefix"; cat "$name"; } >"$name".tmp && mv "$name".tmp "$name"
done
```

The same thing with `find`:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.md" \
    -exec sh -c 'p="${1%.md}";p="${p##*-}";{ echo "$p";cat "$1"; }>"$1".tmp && mv "$1".tmp "$1"' sh {} ';'
```

Comment: `$prefix` must be prepended to the file content, not to the file name.

Comment: @xhienne Well, that wasn't really clear from the question, but ok. Fixed it.

Comment: Agreed that `find -exec "sh -c ... {} ..."` is bad practice but apparently, from OP's comment in their own answer, this was a prerequisite. BTW, like in your answer, `*.md` needs not be quoted.