# What is the function of this script passed to "sed -e"?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

TL;DR- There's a lot going on in the `sed` pattern below, and I'm not sure how the discrete pieces are being composed into an overall command.

---

Bash version: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)`

I'm learning about shell scripting by reading the RBENV codebase file-by-file, and I've encountered the `rbenv-help` file, which includes [this function definition](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/libexec/rbenv-help#L29):

```
extract_initial_comment_block() {
  sed -ne "
    /^#/ !{
      q
    }

    s/^#$/# /

    /^# / {
      s/^# //
      p
    }
  "
}
```

I see how this function is called [further down in the code](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/libexec/rbenv-help#L100), so I know that its first arg is a filename:

```
extract_initial_comment_block < "$filename" | collect_documentation
```

From this I can see that the file represented by "$filename" is being fed as the standard input to the `sed` command.  For the purposes of my question, the knock-on function "collect_documentation" is irrelevant.

I also gather from the name of the function that its purpose is to take a file like [this](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv-exec), and return its summary and usage comments, i.e. lines 2-14 of the linked file.  However, I haven't tested this theory yet, so I may not be 100% correct.

Furthermore, I know [from this StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33160/142469) that the purpose of the `-e` flag is to tell `sed` to interpret the subsequent string as a command (or a collection of commands separated by a newline?).  So it looks like the body of `extract_initial_comment_block` contains 3 separate scripts for `sed` to interpret, in order.  That same StackExchange answer says that `{...}` are used to group commands together, but I'm not sure if that's what is happening in this regex (these regexes?).

As near as I can tell, there are 3 scripts being fed to `sed` here:

```
    /^#/ !{
      q
    }
```

```
    s/^#$/# /
```

```
    /^# / {
      s/^# //
      p
    }
```

However, even within each of these scripts, there are patterns being used (such as `^#` and `!{ q }`) that I'm not able to identify, even after availing myself of resources like [The Linux Data Project](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html).  It seems like there are a lot of moving pieces, and I'm not sure how each script is being composed into a finished product.

I've tried to walk through my thought process in as clear a manner as I can.  Is my train of thought correct so far?  If it's not, where did I veer off-course?  If it is, how can I deduce the meaning of each command that's passed to `sed`?

Comment: The commands  used here are all clearly documented in the [`sed` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html). After reading through that document, which specifically are your questions?

Comment: My main questions were a) whether my assumption that there are 3 different commands being sent to `sed` is correct, and b) what the commands are doing, specifically commands 1 and 3.  I can deduce what command #2 does, if my first assumption is correct, but at the time I wrote the question, this was not certain.

Comment: I wouldn't say the `{...}` command is "clearly" documented.  There are no examples on the man page; indeed, there are only 3 mentions of the `{` character at all.  The last ("Begin a block of commands") is the clearest, but the word "commands" is vague.  Now that I've read the answer below, I can deduce that it means "zero- or one-address commands" such as `a`, `i`, `q`, and `r` mentioned in the command synopsis, but even that synopsis says "This is just a brief synopsis of sed commands to serve as a reminder to those who already know sed".  For newer devs, a different guide may be needed.

Comment: **Now** you're asking the sort of specific questions that should have been included in the first place! It's generally better to update your question to add this sort of information (people may not see it in the comments).

Comment: I feel like the phrase "...there are patterns being used (such as ^# and !{ q }) that I'm not able to identify, even after availing myself of resources like The Linux Data Project" is pretty explicit.  Perhaps the question title could reflect that more clearly.  If you're OK with the title "What is the function of the `{...}` pattern passed to "sed -e"?", then I'll update it accordingly.  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> /^#/ !{
>       q
>     }
> ```

The part between the slashes is a regular expression, where `^` means the start of string and `#` is just the character itself. The pattern selects the lines on which run the associated command. The trailing `!` inverts the sense of the match, and `q` is the command to quit. So this quits the sed program when it sees a line that *doesn't* start with the comment marker `#`.

> ```
>  s/^#$/# /
> ```

`s/a/b/`  **s**ubstitutes a with b, `^` is start of line, `$` end of line, `#` is itself. So this changes line with just a lone `#` to `#`+space.

> ```
> /^# / {
>   s/^# //
>   p
> }
> ```

If the line starts with a `#` and a space (`/^# /`), replace `#` and space with nothing (`s/^# //`) and print the line (`p`). This is where the previous substitution comes handy.

The `-n` option to sed (at the start of the command) tells sed to *not* print the line after executing the script on it, as it would do by default.

Note that the script ignores lines that start with a `#` and *don't* have a space after, including the hashbang lines starting with `#!` that tell the OS which interpreter to use for the script. Might be on purpose for those, but might hide some other lines.

E.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
# some script
#
#this is ignored
# this prints

# this doesn't print any more
whatever
```

turns into

```
some script

this prints
```

Comment: Thank you.  The syntax inside the quotes with the 3 regexes looks really similar to the subsequent function in that file (code [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/libexec/rbenv-help#L53)), which I see uses the `awk` programming language (according to the [man page for awk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html)).  Does the `sed` command in fact use the same language as the `awk` command, or is the syntax passed to `sed` here not considered a "language", in the sense used by the `awk` man page?